# PF 5.3 line chart not working properly with X String values

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.3.
This simple example should result in a chart containing a single dot in the middle of the chart panel.

xhtml:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{myBean.sampleChart}" />
```

bean:

```
private LineChartModel sampleChart;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(){
    sampleChart = new LineChartModel();
    sampleChart.setTitle("Monthly performance");
    sampleChart.setExtender("extLegend");
    sampleChart.setAnimate(true);
    sampleChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("% achievement");
    sampleChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setMin(0);
    sampleChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setMax(100);
    LineChartSeries series = new LineChartSeries();
    series.setLabel("Running");
    series.set("3/2016", 40D);
    sampleChart.addSeries(series);
}
```

See how I'm using "3/2016" as X value? The chart dots and line are not showing up using such Strings. If I use only number Strings, or numbers, such as "3" or 3L, then the chart works properly.

This was working fine with PrimeFaces 4 (p:lineChart & CartesianChartModel).

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1291) about it.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any workaround for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this by adding the following code to change x axis to CategoryAxis:

```
CategoryAxis axis = new CategoryAxis();
sampleChart.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me multiple days of pain and debugging.